# P-Channel MOSFET high side switch in an MPPT buck converter gets very hot with no load

Tags: overheat, p-channel

I am a novice working on an MPPT solar charge controller. Q5 mosfet ([SUP53P06](https://www.vishay.com/docs/68633/sup53p06.pdf)) gets very hot even when I have no load attached.

The circuit is just like below except I have no current sensors in it yet. So ACS712s are missing. And R5 is actually 47K ohm (i had 10k in there as well, same result).

Solar voltage on Q5's source is 18.85V, but it's only 18.41V on drain. Rds for this fet is 0.02 ohms, so I don't understand why there's such a big drop.

The gate is driven via an NPN transistor with a voltage divider since the solar panel has a max of 22V and i think that would exceed Q5's Vgs(max). The gate voltage is 12.4V. (when i had R5 = 10k ohm the gate voltage was about 9V i believe, so almost -10V to the source).

Sorry for my messy schematic and for possibly too of an open ended question but I've spent a couple of days on this and can't seem to figure it out.

Let me know if you have any ideas about what I am missing here. Thank you!

EDIT: The current is at about 50mA at 0 duty cycle (and that's i believe to power arduino nano, not going through the Q5 fet). However if I allow the duty cycle to rise the current goes up to 140mA. Is it shooting through? IR2104 has plenty of dead time built in. Still though, at such low levels I'd expect the fet to be cool as a cucumber.

EDIT: Q3 needs to be flipped in this schematic. It is the proper way in the actual circuit. I've had this circuit power an LED as a test so far, so it functions. I'm just worried about hooking up a bigger load before figuring out what the issue is with the Q5.

[image]

Comment: Where are your design specs?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you are looking for? What info can I provide that would help/is missing?

Comment: Q3 should be an N channel device!

Comment: @mr_js it is. My schematic has it flipped along the y axis. Good catch! But my actual circuit has it right and the circuit does function, it’s just the heat issue with Q5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on the datasheet:**

Remember virtually no DC current flows in or out of a MOSFET gate, so if gate resistor is 22 ohms to 100 ohms it is fine, high enough so Q3 / Q2 do not "ring" with ON/OFF transistions.

A large bypass capacitor is shown between Q3 and Q5 so the output has a stable current source, not affected by Q5 ON resistance.

Comment: NOTE: OP requested deletion of original answer as it contained, along with comments, too much commentary no longer relevant to the actual problem. OP posted a comment explaining his fix for the problem which was to insert a 1000 uF capacitor from Q3/Q5 drain to ground. OP may also add gate resistors per datasheet.